# Ruby: Check number of arguments passed from instantiated class to the method of a module

Tags: ruby, methods, module, arguments

I am trying to find the number of arguments which are passed from my instantiated class to the method of a module.

```
class A
  inclue ModuleA
end

A.new.moduleA_method(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

This is the content in Module A

```
moduleA
   def moduleA_method(arg1, arg2, arg3)
     puts ARGV.size
   end
end
```

ARGV.size prints 0, however it should be 3 as per my understanding.

Comment: `ARGV` is for command line arguments. You want the arity of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html) method to get a method as an object. Then call `arity` to get the number of arguments for the method.

```
MyClass.new.method(:some_method).arity
```

`__method__` returns the name of the current method as a symbol.

Putting it all together:

```
class Foo
  def bar(arg1, arg2)
    self.method(__method__).arity # => 2
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you should also mention the fact that `Method#arity` returns a negative number for methods with default arguments and what does it mean.

Comment: @toro2k the same applies for `*` args which are not clearly defined as having a default although the default is `[]`. Even more interestingly `def some_method(arg1,*rest)` will have an arity of `-2`.

Comment: @engineersmnky You are right, actually `arity` returns a negative integer when the method accepts a variable number of arguments, no matter if they have default value or you have a splatted argument.

Comment: With mandatory positional parameters, optional positional parameters, splat parameter, mandatory keyword parameters, optional keyword parameters, keyword splat parameter, optional block parameter, trying to convey all of that information in a single number is futile. You should use [`Method#parameters`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so firstly no one has mentioned the fact that defining a method signature like this

```
def some_method(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

Will require 3 arguments otherwise you will get an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)` or how ever many you passed in. Thus referencing arity inside the method is useless as you cannot get past the error without knowing the number of arguments needed.

You could however define a method like

```
def some_method(*args)
  puts args.size
end
```

This will collect as many or few arguments as are passed in an will wrap them in an array e.g.

```
some_method 
0
#=> nil
some_method "a","b","c"
3 
#=> nil
```

This allows for complete flexibility of arguments and I think is more what you are looking for based on how I am reading your post

Answer (score 0):

Close but not quite. The [ARGV](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-argv) constant actually contains all the arguments passed to your script rather than to your method. So, if you called the script from the command line with arguments, then they would be in this constant.

If a script called "example.rb" contained:

```
puts ARGV.length
```

And if you called it on the command line like so:

```
> ruby example.rb
```

You would get `0`

If you called it like this:

```
> ruby example.rb an_argument
```

You would get `1`